# Why can't I do ls *.txt in a subshell?

Tags: shell, quoting

```
~$ echo $(ls)  
arguments.txt cecho.sh Desktop Documents Downloads example.txt Music Pictures Public     
~$ echo $(ls "*.txt")  
ls: cannot access *.txt: No such file or directory
```

Why does the 2nd subshell command fails?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `*.txt` and it should work. With quotes shell will look for the literal filename `*.txt`. To explore/experiment, try creating a file with name `*.txt` as `touch '*.txt'` and repeat the command.

Comment: Note that double quotes (at least in `bash` and similar shells like `zsh`) are not the same as single quotes! For example, parameter expansion (`$foo`) is done inside double quotes, but not single quotes.

Answer (score 30):

In the same way that you can't run `ls "*.txt"` in a normal shell, you can't run it in a subshell either. When you put `*.txt` in quotes, you made `ls` search for a literal file called `*.txt` when instead you should be doing this:

```
$ echo $(ls *.txt) # => file.txt otherfile.txt
```

A better way to do this is to not use `ls` at all.

```
$ echo *.txt # => file.txt otherfile.txt
```

Comment: +1 for removing the redundant `ls`.

Comment: Nitpicking: You **can** run `ls -l "*.txt"`. Or at least I can. I do it not often, but when I do, it usually tells me that it couldn't find *.txt ...

Comment: @lngo: That's in the OP's post too